# High Frequency GPIO toggle AVR

Tags: toggle, avr, gpio, freertos, atmelstudio

I have a basic AVR setup with ATmega328P and a FreeRTOS kernel running on it. I want to toggle a GPIO pin set as output at high frequency between 30kHz-60kHz. The frequency of GPIO toggle is continuously determined by other RTOS tasks and function which is between 30kHz-60kHz.

I want to ask how to toggle the GPIO at such high frequencies that are constantly changing. I am using Atmel Studio 7. Please help.

Comment: have you considered using PWM or do you want to toggle it manually ?

Comment: I don't know what's the better way @Julien . If I chose PWM, I can't change the frequency on the go (That's what I think, tell me if I'm wrong). But if I chose normal GPIO, I don't know how to toggle it that fast and also change it's frequency on the go.

Comment: Also depends pretty much on what else you might want your software to do - Toggling signals periodically works pretty well with timed loops in case your software doesn't have anything else to do. It tends to become a bit hairy once you have a lot of interrupts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to change the frequency at about let's say every 2 pulse then software MAY be a solution. If the frequency will stay for several 10th or 100ds of pulses, PWM is definitely the good way to do.

Of course you can manage PWM frequency and period on the go. You will need to read timer/counterX with PWM part of the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf). If you need always 50% duty cycle, §15.7.2 is the best way to configure. If you need both duty cycle and frequency the §15.7.3 is adapted.

Cover all the possible configuration would be to broad to write here but if you start implementation and experience issues you can ask new question.

Comment: After reading some tutorials and datasheet, I have got a rough idea on what I have to do @Julien. So, I am concluding what I understood(correct me if I'm wrong)- When I would change the frequency (by changing the top value), duty cycle would be effected in any case. And thanks for getting me this far.

Comment: @PrabhatNarang It you use method §15.7.2 changing the TOP value will change frequency and configuring `TCCRxA` `COMxA1:0` bits to toogle on overflow you will keep the 50% duty cycle always without need to reconfigure. Of course if you need another duty cycle than 50% this does not work and changing TOP value will change the duty. So you will always need to re-configure both simultaneously